# PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1 for `.split(File.separator)` under windows

Tags: java

The following snippet works fine under linux but gives me error under windows (which is very weird since jvm/jdk is supposed to be OS-agnostic).

```
  File f = ... 
  String[] split = f.getPath().split(File.separator);
```

Here is the error:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\
 ^
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.String.split(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.String.split(Unknown Source)
```

any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is that the backslash is a special character using regexes (escape character for other special characters). You should use

```
String[] split = f.getPath().split("\\\\");
```

in order to split by the sign `\`.

---

I see the problem you have if you want to keep this platform independant. In that case you could do something like this:

```
String splitter = File.separator.replace("\\","\\\\");
String[] split = abc.split(splitter);
```

Comment: Thanks! That saved me some trouble. The weird  part is that "\\" works on windows 10 and crashes on windows 7.

Comment: Ok, the "\\" that works was because of Java8, not because of windows version, which makes more sense.
So in Java7 use "\\\\" and in Java8 use "\\".

Comment: I am using Java8 but still "\\" doesn't seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 5):

You should consider using the Path class introduced with java.nio. It works even if you mix the separators. This code:

```
    Path path = Paths.get("c:\\a\\with spaces/b");

    for(Iterator<Path> it= path.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }
```

prints:

```
a
with spaces
b
```

Comment: Great idea, and much cleaner than having to replace '\\'.  Should consider making this the best one.

Comment: Thanks! With a Path variable, I could simply do `path.getFilename()` and it was done.